# How to merge lines split with "\" at the very end with Python?

Tags: python, regex, string, split

I am now parsing some text. Some lines are very long such that they are splitted into several sub-lines with a "\" at the very end.

I try to use regular expression to merge these sub-lines. However the escaped character "\n" and "\" make me confusing.

Can someone show me how to accomplish this task with Python?

Comment: Can you add some example code where this is being an issue?

Answer (score 2):

```
str1 = """This is a sample with slash \
also some new line characters
This line becomes the second element \
with this line also
"""

print str1.split('\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably mean this:

```
import re

def reg():
    st = r"hi i have a really long line so i have a \ im cool now \n"
    print re.sub(r'\\{1} ', '', st)

reg()
```

Find some way that '\' differs from '\n'. I've used a space after '\'.

Answer (score 1):

If you're reading text from a file like

```
line 1 \
continuation of line 1
```

Then what you need to do is replace the "backslash + line feed" pair of characters with an empty string:

```
content = open('myfile.txt').read()
fixed_content = content.replace('\\\n', '')
```

Answer (score -1):

From the sound of it you can use the srt.split('\n') function.  If you are reading lines from a file just use readlines and it will split them into a list for you.

f=open('file.txt','rb')
lines=f.readlines()

Comment: This should work. See my answer above.